# What is the difference between lipohyalinosis and microatheroma?

Tags: pathophysiology, stroke, arteries-artery, pathogenesis

Lacunar strokes (small-vessel subcortical strokes) are commonly caused by "lipohyalinosis" or "microatheroma"(1). Both mechanisms appear to be related to hypertension and diabetes, but I haven't been able to find a good definition for these terms. What is the difference between these two mechanisms?

Unfortunately this paper titled "Mechanisms in lacunar infarction" doesn't define the terms either...

Source:

1. Horowitz DR, Tuhrim S, Weinberger JM, Rudolph SH. Mechanisms in lacunar infarction. Stroke. 1992 Mar;23(3):325-7. doi: 10.1161/01.str.23.3.325. PMID: 1542890. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1542890/

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, a microatheroma is a small atheroma. An artheroma is what's commonly known as a plaque. It's a mass ***on*** the interior wall of arteries:

https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/atheroma

> atheroma [ath″er-o´mah] an abnormal mass of fatty or lipid material
> with a fibrous covering, existing as a discrete, **raised plaque
> within the intima of an artery**. adj., adj atherom´atous.

Lipohyalinosis, on the other hand, is a degenerative disease marked by lipids that accumulate ***within*** the walls of blood vessels:

https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/lipohyalinosis

> lipohyalinosis (lī-pō-hī′ă-lĭn-ō″sĭs) Degenerative changes in small
> blood vessels, marked by the accumulation of a glassy- or
> waxy-appearing lipid **within the vessel wall**. This type of vascular
> degeneration occurs in hypertension and atherosclerosis, and
> predisposes patients to small infarcts, esp. in penetrating arteries
> of the brain.

Both things are capable of narrowing arteries and reducing blood flow, which can cause a  stroke. Plaques can also rupture, spilling plaque material into the bloodstream, which can then travel to a point where it lodges in a smaller artery and blocks it, which can also cause a stroke.